# Viewing list saved into a redis hash

Tags: redis

I've saved a list into a hash but cannot figure out how to retrieve contents of the hash. Firstly, here is some code to create the list:

`127.0.0.1:6379> LPUSH list1  'dc:39:79:ab:cd:ef' 
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> LPUSH list1 '2014-07-21'
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> LPUSH list1 'Success'
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> LPUSH list1 'Miscellaneous notes about the install. Can be as long as you want'
(integer) 4`

Now I create a hash and assign the value of one key to list1:

`127.0.0.1:6379> hset hash 'RKT1234' list1
(integer) 1`

How can I print the entire list saved inside hash['RKT1234'] ?

`127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall hash
1) "RKT1234"
2) "list1"`

127.0.0.1:6379> hvals hash
1) "list1"

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to store a list as a value in a hash. You are not doing what you think you are doing as Redis does not support nested data structures. In `hset hash 'RKT1234' list1` you are not storing the list, just a string name: "list1".

In order to get the contents of list you need to first get the name of the list from the hash, then get the contents of the list in a second call.

So your sequence looks like this:

```
# returns "list1"
hvals hash 
lrange list1 0 -1
# returns the contents of list1
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply and clarification regarding redis' (in)ability to work with nested data structures. I don't see how the code snippet you posted can help.

Can we save the name returned by
**hvals hash** into a variable and later call **lrange** on it? Obviously, I don't want to hard-code the list name on which **lrange** will be called.
thanks

Comment: Yes, that is precisely how you'd do it. As you didn't post the language you are using I had no way of knowing and demonstrating it that way, so I stuck with the redis-cli commands as you used them. :)

Comment: Hi Bill,

I should've mentioned that I intended to use python to read/write data to redis. Based on what you wrote earlier, I got the desired result with my script:
`r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', db=0)`

`x = r.hvals('hash')`

`print r.lrange(x[0], 0, -1)`

`['Misellaneous notes about the install. Can be as long as you want', 'Success', '2014-07-21', 'dc:39:79:ab:cd:ef']`

Thanks a lot!